# Do I need to close Response.body for Custom Error Handling in Feign Client

Tags: netflix-feign, spring-cloud-feign, feign

I have defined custom `ErrorDecoder` for Feign Client with reference to this [wiki](https://github.com/OpenFeign/feign/wiki/Custom-error-handling) page.

In my `ErrorDecoder` I am reading response body by invoking `response.body()`

Do I need to `close` response in my `ErrorDecoder` when reading `InputStream`. Or Feign will handle closing of `response`?

I checked `SynchronousMethodHandler` which invokes custom error decoder. This has `finally` block

```
} finally {
    if (shouldClose) {
        Util.ensureClosed(response.body());
}
```

Since there is no guidelines from the wiki page.

Answer (score 0):

If you are reading the `Response` object directly you **must** close the body yourself, our you will leak resources.  This is also true if you return `Response` objects as part of your Feign interface.